# Tableau: how to calculate a group (or set) based on another column data

Tags: tableau-api

Just started learning Tableau, would appreciate your tips on the following:
Have 2 columns of data strings, one to many values. Example:
yellow -> banana
yellow -> sun

Instead of duplicating the lines, I would like to present it as a group:
yellow -> banana & sun.

I can not do it manually, as data set is huge and changing. So I need a condition from the "yellow" column.

Could you help me with a query, please? Thank you!

Comment: try this one :https://community.tableau.com/thread/242231

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.
1. Create a table in excel/txt/csv/database that takes those values and assigned a grouping value, and join it in the data model. You would only need to do this once, and update it as needed.
Ex:

```
Time   | Color
---------------
Banana | Yellow
Sun    | Yellow
```

2. Another would be to create a calculated field with if statements if there are commonalities in the list.

Option one would be much more efficient if its a large list and would require less maintenance than you're currently doing